# How to make text selectable in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm using `<div ng-bind-html="data.html"></div>` to display a html content, but I found that the text in this div cannot be selected.

How can I make text selectable?

I cannot select in chrome and ios device

Comment: Thats wierd, in the example in the documentation the html seems to be selectable (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: Do you have a `-webkit-user-select: none;`? Maybe directly from ionic? Try to give an ID to that div and style it with `-webkit-user-select: all !important;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had Come across, similar situation. where one of our application need to work on desktop browser chrome etc. since it was Ionic app text select was disabled by default. here what i did.

```
body {
 -webkit-user-select: auto !important;
.scroll {
    -webkit-user-select: inherit;
  }
}
```

May be helpful for someone.

Comment: `-webkit-user-select: text` on the proper node did the trick for me